# Java socket programming problem

Tags: sockets

Hey,
I am trying to run this socket programming code.

This is the code on the server side -

```
package sockettest;    

import java.net.*;    
import java.io.*;     

public class Server {    
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

ServerSocket serverSocket = null;   
try 
{  
  serverSocket = new ServerSocket(139);   
} 
catch (IOException e) 
{  
  System.err.println("not able to listen on port");  
  System.exit(1);  
}

Socket clientSocket = null;   
try 
{
   clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();    
} 
catch (IOException e) 
{   
   System.err.println("Accept failed.");   
   System.exit(1);   
}

PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true); // Out is Outputstream is used to write to the Client .   
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream())); // in is used to read the Client's input. 
String inputLine, outputLine;     

out.println("Hey! . Who are you?"); // Writes to client as "Hey! . Who are you?"

while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)         
{
 // Reads the input from the Client. if it is "bye" the program ends.

   if (inputLine.equalsIgnoreCase("Bye"))   
   {    
       out.println("Bye");   
       break;   
   }   
   else    
   {    
      out.println("Hello Mr. " + inputLine);    
   }    
 }     
 out.close();    
 in.close();     
 clientSocket.close();     
 serverSocket.close();     
}     
}
```

This is the code running on the client side -

```
import java.io.*;    
import java.net.*;     

public class Client 
{      
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {     

Socket kkSocket = null;     
PrintWriter out = null;     
BufferedReader in = null;     

try 
{     
   kkSocket = new Socket("192.168.2.3", 139);     
   out = new PrintWriter(kkSocket.getOutputStream(), true); // Out may be used to write to server from the client       
   in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(kkSocket.getInputStream())); // in will be used to read the lines sent by the Server.      
} 
catch (UnknownHostException e)
{     
   System.err.println("Unidentified host.");     
   System.exit(1);     
}
catch (IOException e) 
{          
   System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O for the connection to.");      
   System.exit(1);      
}      


BufferedReader stdIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));     
String fromServer;     
String fromClient;      

while ((fromServer = in.readLine()) != null) {      
System.out.println("Server: " + fromServer);      
if (fromServer.equals("Bye"))     
break;     

fromClient = stdIn.readLine();     
if (fromClient != null) {      
System.out.println("Client: " + fromClient);      
out.println(fromClient);       
}      

}       


out.close();      
 in.close();      
stdIn.close();       
kkSocket.close();
}     
}
```

I'm running the codes on eclipse in both the client and the server side. Using netstat -an command in cmd prompt, i can see that a connection has been established between the client and the server but i cannot communicate and eclipse is not showing any output too. What seems to be wrong??

Comment: ... and what is your question?

Comment: Hi, what's the problem exactly? Code not compiling? You don't know how it works? And how it's currently structured will allow only one client to connect.

Comment: I am sorry. I have edited it and added my question at the end. Please read it and reply accordingly. Thanks!!

Comment: Your code, without indentation, it is a mess to read. Give your readers the courtesy of reading well-formatted code. Also, what exactly do you mean by **'cannot communicate'**? Don't give vague descriptions. Aim to be precise. Nothing is being sent to the server? The server doesn't receive anything? Did you try running the server on the eclipse debugger with a breakpoint right on the server's input while loop?

Comment: @luis.espinal : Nothing is being sent to the server or client. I will try running it on the eclipse debugger as you have told.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't told us what the problem is. However, from a cursory glance at your code, I would advise against listening on port 139 as this is already used by NetBios under Windows and may cause a conflict.

Comment: And on UNIX, you need to be root to be allowed to open ports < 1024

Comment: I am sorry. I have edited it and added my question at the end. Please read it and reply accordingly. Thanks. Can you tell me some port which will be free??

Comment: @BenoitThiery : Thanks for the reply but I am running it on Windows Vista.

Answer (score 0):

also your Server code is missing 
the initialization of inputLine, 
e.g

> String inputline = "";

before the while loop

Comment: You don't need that. The OP codes makes some actions that are typically considered bad practices in Java. In fact, it feels like the OP is coding in a very C-like manner. Having said that, initializing a String variable with "", specially when it is immediately initialized with something else, that is also a vain thing to do. This is Java, not C. These two languages have very different coding standards and best practices. One cannot simply take from one and force it into the other.

Comment: I am sorry. I have edited it and added my question at the end. Please read it and reply accordingly. Thanks!!

Comment: The string inputline is initialized. 
      "String inputLine, outputLine;"
after the line BufferdReader in=.... Isn't that enough?

Comment: @Benoit - you'd be surprise at the amount of working Java programmers I've found that actually do that (init'ing String variables with "", thinking it's actually needed.) Sad and funny at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

keep in mind that Socket's are blocked if you read or write...

your client is reading all the time because it waits for every information on the server 
until it is null

and your server also reads all the time and is waiting for any input..

so as long as server and client are waiting for input, no one will receive any data.

try to think of a protocol to communicate between the server and the client. 
e.g

```
Sever to Client: Hello Who are you?
Client receives Data and replies: Client
Server receives Information: You Are now authorized, what ya gonna do?
and so on ^^
```

also out.flush() is needed to send a message

Comment: Both the client and the server have been trying to communicate but nothing is being sent to either side. And where should I add the out.flush()?

Comment: I just tried your code, everything is fine except the port, i changed it to 33139 and the host to localhost and everything works